# How can I print the bash output of the java stack-trace to a file in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, bash, stack-trace

This is my case:

Even though the command I run is not so relevant, I'll still include it.

`user@machine:$ java -classpath /home/user/mysql.jar:/home/user/jericho-html.jar:/home/user JavaFile`

I have introduced an error in the java code, so the command gives the output:

```
[ERROR] null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception
[ERROR] input:
null
  at JavaFile.main(JavaFile.java:111)
```

What I want to achieve is to write this output to a file, and then to send the file to my e-mail address. I've sorted the e-mail stuff out, but I can't figure out how to write this output to a file.

I've tried adding `>> filename.txt` to the end of the command, but that does nothing. And I can't locate the java log files on the system, if they even exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to redirect stderr to your file. Use `&>>` instead `>>` for redirection. That way you will redirect all output (stderr and stdout).

Answer (score 4):

Using `>>` appends the standard output to a file.

You want to pipe the standard error to a file with `java (...) 2> errors.txt` (or use `>>` to append to a file)

Comment: Thank you! In the end I went for `&>>` in order to append both stderr and stdout to a file.